# Need help regarding using the single shift character set along with locking shift character set for the national language in SMS

Tags: sms, gsm

I am having this application when I need to send the sms in the national language hence I have defined the [National Language Locking Shift in the UDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Data_Header). Every thing was all good but now I need to use few characters of the National Language single shift and after searching a few place , I came to know about using the escape control that is /x1B or 27 before the extended set of character that basically helps me to use the character set of [Basic character set.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#cite_note-3G-TS-23.038-2)

What I am looking for is more precisely a way to use the single shift character set for the national language with the locking shift character set.

Any help, reference or guidance appreciated.

Comment: Why dont you simply use UCS charset ?

Comment: @Marvin because we are sending SMS in Indian regional languages.

Comment: I thought all languages are covered with UTF-16 (which is basically same as UCS2 at SMS).
Maybe this will help:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#National_language_shift_tables